# How to search for a specific value in a multiple dictionary list, then extract another value from the same list?

Tags: json, dictionary, ansible, conditional-statements, jinja2

After debugging results of a task, I want to be able to get the corresponding uuid just by entering a specific snapshot_name.

This is the output of the "result" variable:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "date": "Mon, 22 May 2023 03:39:34 GMT",
        "elapsed": 0,
        "expires": "0",
        "failed": false,
        "json": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "created_time": 1684493611741165,
                    "deleted": false,
                    "logical_timestamp": 1,
                    "snapshot_name": "Snapshot 1",
                    "uuid": "ffa972f7-25b7-4d0c-8e92-2e7afef863c4"
                },
                {
                    "created_time": 1684502215147173,
                    "deleted": false,
                    "logical_timestamp": 1,
                    "snapshot_name": "vm snapshot",
                    "uuid": "6f1kc72a-8916-4edd-9639-c2823b57a1cb"
                },
                {
                    "created_time": 1684725225721634,
                    "deleted": false,
                    "logical_timestamp": 1,
                    "snapshot_name": "new",
                    "uuid": "ad872bde-3a94-411f-8f89-5f5ad55e4ffa"
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "grand_total_entities": 3,
                "total_entities": 3
            }
        },
        "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "redirected": false,
        "server": "envoy"
    }
}
```

This is my playbook:

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result }}"

- name: Snapshot name to look for
  set_fact:
    snapname: "{{ snapname }}"

- name: Getting the uuid of the above snapname
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.json.entities[*].uuid }}"
  when: result.json.entities[*].snapshot_name == snapname
```

Snapname is a variable as I want to be able to be able to enter different snapname values in ansible controller itself, so it is meant to be a changeable variable. Then let ansible search for the snapname value and get its corresponding uuid.

I got this error for the last task in my playbook:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'result.json.entities[*].snapshot_name == snapname' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '*'. String: {% if result.json.entities[*].snapshot_name == snapname %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to be in '/var/lib/awx/projects/Nutanix/roles/vm_restore/tasks/vm_restore.yml': line 46, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: debug\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

How do I write my playbook in a way that when the value of snapname == "vm snapshot", it will search for "vm snapshot" in "snapshot_name" in all the lists, then get the corresponding uuid?

For example, search which list has "vm_snapshot", then output the uuid, "6f1kc72a-8916-4edd-9639-c2823b57a1cb".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either *json_query*

```yaml
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ result.json.entities|
                  json_query('[?snapshot_name == `vm snapshot`].uuid') }}"
```

, or *selectattr* and *map*

```
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ result.json.entities|
                  selectattr('snapshot_name', '==', 'vm snapshot')|
                  map(attribute='uuid') }}"
```

Both tasks give the same result

```yaml
  msg:
  - 6f1kc72a-8916-4edd-9639-c2823b57a1cb
```

---

The code below shows how to substitute a variable

```yaml
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ result.json.entities|json_query(_query) }}"
       vars:
         snapname: vm snapshot
         _query: '[?snapshot_name == `{{ snapname }}`].uuid'
```

```yaml
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ result.json.entities|
                  selectattr('snapshot_name', '==', snapname)|
                  map(attribute='uuid') }}"
       vars:
         snapname: vm snapshot
```

---

But, if the values of *snapshot_name* are unique, you can create a dictionary first

```yaml
  snapshot_uuid: "{{ result.json.entities|
                     items2dict(key_name='snapshot_name', value_name='uuid') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  snapshot_uuid:
    Snapshot 1: ffa972f7-25b7-4d0c-8e92-2e7afef863c4
    new: ad872bde-3a94-411f-8f89-5f5ad55e4ffa
    vm snapshot: 6f1kc72a-8916-4edd-9639-c2823b57a1cb
```

The search is trivial now.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    result:
      date: Mon, 22 May 2023 03:39:34 GMT
      elapsed: 0
      expires: '0'
      failed: false
      json:
        entities:
        - created_time: 1684493611741165
          deleted: false
          logical_timestamp: 1
          snapshot_name: Snapshot 1
          uuid: ffa972f7-25b7-4d0c-8e92-2e7afef863c4
        - created_time: 1684502215147173
          deleted: false
          logical_timestamp: 1
          snapshot_name: vm snapshot
          uuid: 6f1kc72a-8916-4edd-9639-c2823b57a1cb
        - created_time: 1684725225721634
          deleted: false
          logical_timestamp: 1
          snapshot_name: new
          uuid: ad872bde-3a94-411f-8f89-5f5ad55e4ffa
        metadata:
          grand_total_entities: 3
          total_entities: 3
      msg: OK (unknown bytes)
      pragma: no-cache
      redirected: false
      server: envoy

    snapshot_uuid: "{{ result.json.entities|
                       items2dict(key_name='snapshot_name', value_name='uuid') }}"
      
  tasks:

     - debug:
         var: snapshot_uuid

     - debug:
         msg: "{{ result.json.entities|
                  selectattr('snapshot_name', '==', 'vm snapshot')|
                  map(attribute='uuid') }}"

     - debug:
         msg: "{{ result.json.entities|
                  json_query('[?snapshot_name == `vm snapshot`].uuid') }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as you can see in my playbook, I have a set_fact variable, snapname. How can I input this snapname variable into the json_query and selectattr map? I have tried "{{ result.json.entities|selectattr('snapshot_name', '==', 'snapname')|map(attribute='uuid') }}" and "{{result.json.entities|selectattr('snapshot_name', '==', '{{ snapname }}')|map(attribute='uuid') }}", and also tried the same for the json_query one, but the formatting is still wrong.

Comment: I added examples of how to substitute a variable. In the case of *json_query* it is easier to put the query into a variable. You're welcome!